# Java Scanline fill

Tags: java, graphics, 3d

I am currently developing an application and want to understand the core principles of computer graphics. I was wandering if anyone can provide a formula to check if a point in three variables (x,y,z) intersects a line that consist of two points (x1,y1,z1) and (x2,y2,z2)

Comment: math.stackexchange.com is what you must be looking for !

Comment: Yea, but i don't understand some of they're symbols

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say if you wanted to find if point0 =(x0,y0,z0) intersects line which cross at point1=(x1,y1,z1) and  point2 = (x2,y2,z2).

Formula to check if point0 lies on line (point1->point2) would be to check if   (X0,y0,z0) = (x1,y1,z1) + t(x2-x1,y2-y1,z2-z1).

For any value of t that is constant for x , y and z axes.
so 
x0 = x1 + t(x2-x1)
y0 = y1 + t(y2-y1)
etc..

Comment: what would x3 be? so I can assign any value to t to check?

Comment: again I can assign any value to t? if the statement is always true then it intersects the line?

Comment: You cannot, either decide on suitable value of t that gives required value of x0 or pick a value of x0 to give value of t.

Comment: Since I have point A and point B can I substitute point0 with the midpoint of point A and point B to get the value of t then, use the same formula to check if point0 intersects the line?

Comment: yes but be aware if you correctly picked  the midpoint of A and B it would be sure to intersect line A and B.

Comment: Thanks that was a lot of help